# How do I multiply lists of list of numbers?

Tags: racket

I know how to multiply a list of numbers using map or foldr.

```
(define (multiply lst a)
 (foldr (lambda (v r) (cons (* a v) r)) empty lst))

(check-expect(multiply (list 1 2 3) 5) (list 5 10 15))
```

My question is, how would I apply this to a list of list of numbers?
For instance:

```
(multiply (list (list 3 1 4)(list 6)(list 3 5)))
```

Comment: Can you find a way to combine `map` with `multiply`?

Comment: What result do you expect for the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (multiply lst a)
  (map (λ (xs) (* a xs)) lst))

(define (f lol a)
  (map (λ (xs) (multiply xs a)) lol))

(multiply '(1 2 3) -1)
(f '((3 1 4) (6) (3 5)) -1)
```